# Why is Rake not able to invoke multiple tasks consecutively?

Tags: ruby, rake, task

I have a Rake task which I have simplified below.
I'm using Ruby 1.9 on Windows.

Perhaps you would like to guess the outcome of calling the Rake task "list_all_levels" below? It should be:

```
"Hello level 1"
"Hello level 2"
"Hello level 3"
```

But for reasons unknown to me, it prints only "Hello level 1" and then stops.

That is, it always invokes only the first task.
If I change the first line to pass the arg "42", it would print "Hello level 42" and then stop.

I'm wondering why does it **not** invoke the task 3 times and print all 3 lines?
And is there any way to get it to work how I would expect?

```
task :list_all_levels => [] do
    Rake::Task[:list].invoke 1
    Rake::Task[:list].invoke 2
    Rake::Task[:list].invoke 3
end

task :list, [:level] => [] do |t, args|
    puts "Hello level #{args.level}"
end
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The issue is that [`invoke`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html#M000119) only invokes the task if it is *needed*.  Running `rake --trace` shows:

```
(in /tmp/ruby)
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Execute default
** Invoke list (first_time)
** Execute list
Hello level 1
** Invoke list 
** Invoke list
```

So you can see it's trying to invoke the task `:list` two more times.  But one thing you can do is to change the body of the main task to:

```
task :default => [] do
    Rake::Task[:list].invoke 1
    Rake::Task[:list].reenable
    Rake::Task[:list].invoke 2
    Rake::Task[:list].reenable
    Rake::Task[:list].invoke 3
end
```

then the `:list` task is needed again and it correctly prints out all 3 statements.

The cleaner way to do it is to [use `execute` rather than `invoke`](http://chrisroos.co.uk/blog/2007-12-06-ruby-rake-invoke-vs-execute):

```
task :default => [] do
    Rake::Task[:list].execute 1
    Rake::Task[:list].execute 2
    Rake::Task[:list].execute 3
end

task :list, [:level] => [] do |t, args|
    puts "Hello level #{args}"
end
```

That changes your `puts` statement to use just `args` rather than `args.level` for some reason.  There are some other caveats with using `execute` over `invoke` described in the link above.

Comment: Be careful with if changing it to `execute` @PandaWood as they are not exactly the same => [rake execute vs invoke](http://chrisroos.co.uk/blog/2007-12-06-ruby-rake-invoke-vs-execute)

Comment: This seems very counter-intuitive to me. Any ideas why they made it like this?

Comment: @marcovtwout Because Rake is originally built to replace Make, whose aim is to avoid duplicated compiling. It looks very intuitive to me.

Answer (score 8):

You need to re-enable the task before the new execution, for this, you just need to execute the method reenable. Like the user Mark Rushakoff mentioned.

```
Rake::Task[:list].reenable
```