# How to execute multiple arguments in a single rake using sidekiq worker?

Tags: arguments, rake, sidekiq, worker

I am new to sidekiq, i just created sidekiq worker, when i run the sidekiq worker, it executes only the first rake task

I want to execute single rake with two different combinations of arguments

e.g

```
def perform
  Rake::Task['test:fetch'].invoke("foo", "bar", 1, 1)
  Rake::Task['test:fetch'].invoke("foo1", "bar1", 1, 1)
end
```

how to execute the above with interval of 5 minutes, should i run the rake 2 times or any other method to pass two diffrent arguments?

Answer (score 0):

That's how Rake works.  Read the rake documentation about tasks and invoke()

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-enable rake tasks after calling the `invoke` method, or use `execute` to avoid re-enabling.

Using invoke, your code might look like this:

```
def perform
  Rake::Task['test:fetch'].invoke("foo", "bar", 1, 1)
  Rake::Task['test:fetch'].reenable
  Rake::Task['test:fetch'].invoke("foo1", "bar1", 1, 1)
end
```

Using execute, your code might look like this:

```
def perform
  task_args = {:arg1 => "foo", :arg2 => "bar", :arg3 => 1, :arg4 => 1 }
  Rake::Task['test:fetch'].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new(task_args.keys, task_args.values))

  task_args = {:arg1 => "foo1", :arg2 => "bar1", :arg3 => 1, :arg4 => 1 }
  Rake::Task['test:fetch'].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new(task_args.keys, task_args.values)
end
```

For some more explanation see here: [Why is Rake not able to invoke multiple tasks consecutively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532427/why-is-rake-not-able-to-invoke-multiple-tasks-consecutively)